# open source user-security/password scheme

Tags: android, ios, security, mobile, passwords

I've read numerous discussions lately about different forms of security for mobile devices outside of the typical password/pin code setup.

The articles talk about recognizing the touchscreen as a human input device and that security measures in apps ought to evolve for that as well.

One such concept involved a graphical keylock like one you would see on a safe. The would have to use multiple fingers to twist it to the correct combination. I haven't done any OpenGL stuff so I wouldn't really know how to develop that, has it been done, is it open source?

I did read this:  [Security Beyond a Username/Password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908242/security-beyond-a-username-password) , but I am looking for other opinions.

Thanks for any suggestions and resources. Also please post resources instead of voting to close if it comes down to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cann't say for all mobile devices, but iOS SDK provides [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, you may [create a subclass](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW2) that UIGestureRecognizer that recognizes a distinctive gesture, character or some kind of gesture combination (in your case). I assume another mobile technologies also have similar methods to recognize keylock characters.

Hope it help you.